# Is it acceptable to ask questions that are currently unsolved?

Tags: discussion

Sometimes problems will just appear in my head, and even though I'll work on it for a long while, nothing good will come to me. So then I'll tell the problem to my friends. Eventually, they'll either get an answer or come back and say something along the lines of

> This is really hard! So what's the solution?

And at this point I tell them that I don't HAVE a solution, and often they'll get mad at me.

So in short, is it OK to ask these unsolved puzzles on Puzzling? For some people I think answering a question that doesn't have a definite answer puts them off a bit, so if there were some sort of an 'unanswered' tag, where the question asker can acknowledge that he/she has not yet solved the problem, that would be cool.

<sub><sup>sometimes the best questions are the ones that aren't answered yet</sup></sub>

Comment: See [this](http://meta.puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/2939/puzzle-askers-should-say-if-they-dont-know-the-answer) and [this](http://meta.puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/2930/is-it-appropriate-to-pose-a-puzzle-where-i-dont-know-the-answer) related question